# Adding optional clauses to a Groovy DSL

Tags: groovy, dsl

I am developing a DSL with Groovy and I have run into the following problem. I have a method which performs some action on an object with the given parameters.

```
def run(x) {
    [with:{ y -> foo(x,y) }]
}

run "thing" with "param"    // evaluates to foo("thing","param")
```

Now, assume I want to add a default functionality to my DSL:

```
def runDefault(x) {
    foo(x)
}

runDefault "thing"          // evaluates to foo("thing")
```

Is there a way to combine the two into a single function, such that the `with "param"` part becomes an optional clause? I want to be able to use the DSL as shown below:

```
run "thing" with "param"    // should do foo("thing","param")
run "thing"                 // should do foo("thing")
```

Comment: Think you're either going to need a different method to `run` with no parameters, or you're going to need a "capping method" to execute the call (like `build()` in the standard builder pattern)

Comment: The closest I have gotten is adding a default handler to the map returned by run, which runs the default case, i.e. `def run(x) {
    [with:{ y -> foo(x,y) }].withDefault{ k -> foo(x) }
}` and called as `run "thing" _`

Comment: Is it an issue if both `foo(x)` and `foo(x,y)` are called when calling `run "thing" with "param"`?

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to distinguish both calls in the run-method, you could do something like this:

```
def run(x) {
    switch (x) {
    case 'foo':
        println "foo($x)"; break;
    case 'bar': 
        [with:{ y -> println "bar($x,$y)" }]; break;
    }
}
run "bar" with "param"
run "foo"
```